# append column from one table to another table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose i have one table named A with 3 columns(1 id column),and a table named B with two columns(1 id column).Table A and table B can join using column id.

Now I want to append one column from table B to table A by sql statements。so after executing,table A will have 4 columns.Both table A and table B have million rows,how can I do it efficiently?

Comment: Why not just use a view?

Comment: Why not just query the joined tables?

Comment: Are you duplicating the column and will have to maintain it both tables (if so see previous comments), or is this a one-off update and you are going to drop table B or at least that column afterwards - so the data will then *only* exist on table A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a one-off consolidation of tables and you have a reason to do this rather than using a join (with or without a view):

```
alter table a add (col4 varchar2(10)); -- or whatever data type you actually need

merge into a
using b
on (b.id = a.id)
when matched then update set a.col4 = b.col4;
```

You could do a correlated updated:

```
update a set col4 = (
  select col4 from b where b.id = a.id
);
```

but a merge is probably going to be quicker.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 steps to perform:

- Changing the data model (ie. specifying the additional column for A)
- Fill the column with suitable values.

These operations can be folded together if you can afford the resources to temporarily hold the data contained in A and B twice:

```
CREATE TABLE C AS (
    SELECT a.id
         , a.col2
         , a.col3
         , b.col2 AS col4
      FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b ON ( b.id = a.id )
);

DROP TABLE A;
RENAME C TO A;
```

While the Alex Poole's answer is more efficient, the above solution works on oracle versions before 9i (esoteric) and on other rdbms ( syntax to rename the table might differ a bit, eg. `alter table C rename to A` in postgresql 9.x+)