# Appending columns from a created table to an Existing table

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose i have a table named A and i created another table, B. These tables have a related column called 'customer. This customer column houses the customer id of every customer.

I want to use table A for an analysis but I need the other columns existing in B added/appended to table A, which will increase the number of columns in A. The appending should be based on matched customer id (from the customer column in both tables).

I don't want to use a join for this. I want all the data i need to be in a table.

Is it possible to achieve this?

I saw this on a related [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51327495/append-column-from-one-table-to-another-table-in-oracle) post:

alter table a add (col4 varchar2(10)); -- or whatever data type you actually need

merge into a
using b
on (b.id = a.id)
when matched then update set a.col4 = b.col4;

Tried it on dummy tables i created on Apex but didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

RTM on the SQL JOIN. You may join the two tables on the columns that are related. Like: select a.*, b.* from a join b on a.client_id=b.client_id. You may create a view  using that select or, eventually create a materialized view. RTM on those, try something, and if you don't succeed then post some concrete question giving the data structures that are relevant for your business case so that one may also give a specific answer.
Or, if it is only a one time thing you may create table as select.
It would be a performance killer to alter table add column(or columns) and then update that column (or columns)

Comment: Exactly; Godwin, saying that "you don't want to use join" is exactly **opposite** of what you should do. Altering the table and de-normalizing data mode is what you do NOT want to do. Alternatively, consider creating a **view** (which would, obviously, use join) and then select from that view directly (instead of writing query with joins).

Comment: Ok. Thank you all for your responses. Will go with this..